# How to save a text locally when a button is clicked?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to make a button where once the button is clicked it changes a dynamic text field from 100 to 0, and if clicked again from 0 to 100. When I exit the game, I want it to save what the user's last number was. If he exited with a "0" I want a 0 to show up the next time the user opens the game. I have made the following code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.ui.Mouse;

var onoff:Number;
onoff = 100
options_mc.onoff_txt.text = String(onoff);
options_mc.sound_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mute);
options_mc.test3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, test3);
function mute(event:MouseEvent)
{
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("options");
if(so.data.onoff == 100)
{
so.data.onoff = 0
options_mc.onoff_txt.text = String(onoff);
so.flush();
}
else if(so.data.onoff == 0)
{
so.data.onoff = 100
options_mc.onoff_txt.text = String(onoff);
so.flush();
}

 }
```

My problem with this code is that it's not changing the text field when the button is clicked! Could you please help on what I have done wrong?

Comment: what happens when you do `options_mc.onoff_txt.text = "something";` ?

Comment: It updates the dynamic text to the value of onoff

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't initialize the sharedobject in a function, I would make it outside. However rather than explaining the entire reasoning, I would like you to [this](http://as3gametuts.com/2012/02/28/actionscript-saving-and-loading-tutorial/). Whole tutorial on saving and loading, as well as a clicking value which will be relevant to what you're doing.